# performance and the use statment PHP, Laravel 4.x

Tags: php, performance, import, laravel, laravel-4

Are there performance considerations when importing classes with the `use` statement in PHP and more specifically laravel 4.x ?

for example often times i have many `use` statements in my controllers as such:

```
use OrganisationController;
use Input;
use Redirect;
use Validator;
use View;
use Organisation;
use Sentry;
use User;
use Str;
use Lang;
use Application;
use Job;
use Upload;


class ApplicationController extends OrganisationController {

...
```

Comment: Why you use so many use cases? if you autoload your controller, you do not need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it should not effect on performance because, when you use a class that is not in the same namespace you use it with a preceding backslash like

```
\View::make(...);
```

This way you just telling that, the `View` class is within the global `namespace`, to make the code clean you can use `use` statement top of your class like

```
use \View, \Redirect, \Validator; // more
class WhatEver extends BaseController {
    function index()
    {
        //...
        return View::make(...);
    }
}
```

So, in either way, `php` is loading (include/require) the class whenever it founds any use of the class but when it's not in the scope of current namespace you must provide the namespace and it could be directly from the code like

```
\View::make(...);
```

Or maybe using a `use` statement to keep your code clean but in both ways, `php` is loading the `class` during run time (if not already loaded) but you have to provide the right location (with namespace).